# Securing ActiveMQ REST API

Tags: activemq-classic

Has anyone configured ActiveMQ REST API access in such a way that the username created in jetty-realm.properties does not have any access to the Admin Console?

If so, does anyone have any sample jetty.xml and jetty-realm.propeteis examples that they are willing to share?

Thanks in advance!